# 2 Factor Authentication in SSH using public key and PAM

Tags: ssh, authentication, pam

I'm trying to setup 2 Factor Authentication. I want the user to login successfully if:

- The public private/public key matches (authentication method: publickey) or the password is correct
- My pam authentication method is successful.

The second authentication method is a PAM file. So I place it into `/usr/lib/pam/` and added `auth       required       my_pam_module.so` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.
So far I can either log in using the (publickey method) or (a password and whatever is required by me pam module). So I added `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive` in `/etc/sshd_config` and now I'm required to have the public key, password, and "whatever is required by me pam module".

What lines do I need to change in order to achieve what I described above? I'm using Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9). If you aren't familiar with Mac, it could also help what you'd do on your Linux system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy for "publickey->password->your_module" or "password->your_module". Can't find the way to remove password from the first chain

publickey,keyboard-interactive - means that publickey auth will be used and keyboard-interactive after that (kind of logical AND), replace comma with space for logical OR, like

***AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam keyboard-interactive:pam***

Comment: When I write `keyboard-interactive:pam` in the config, I'm  getting this error: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: Try to run ssh client in verbose mode, it will give you more information what's going wrong. Like, 'ssh -vvv <hostname>'

Comment: here is the verbose log of ssh: http://pastebin.com/hXTaCJ6f. You can also find relevant parts of my server log below (the most recent things sshd was reporting). Do I need to replace pam by "my_pam_method"?

Comment: Just wondering, have you added "ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes" and "UsePAM yes" to sshd config?

Comment: It wasn't set to yes but I changed it, although nothing has changed (still getting the same error). Did it work for you? And if so, what OpenSSL are you using?

Comment: Yep, it works fine for me. There are some my config files, sshd_conf - http://pastebin.com/19uve9Mr and /etc/pam.d/sshd (pretty much standard ubuntu file, just added pam_google_authenticator.so) - http://pastebin.com/UdXx8qxy

As a result it's either certificate + pwd + google auth pam module or just pwd + google auth. 

Openssl - 1.0.1